# Undo comment flagging

Tags: support, flags, comments

Just now I flagged [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801718/why-can-outer-java-classes-access-inner-class-private-members#comment34594235_1801768) for moderator attention, upon which I realized it was 4 months old and probably irrelevant. Is there any way for me to unflag it?

Comment: I don't believe so. The flag will likely be rejected though if it was inappropriate (and add to your "rejected flag" count which may lead to a flag ban if you accrue too many). Take it as a lesson to be more vigilant in the future and double check before you submit a flag.

Comment: Haha, flag it!!

Comment: Is that actually the thing I should do here?

Comment: Sure. If the linked duplicate answers this question to your satisfaction do flag it. There's no negative affect to you and there's a positive one in that people who come across this in the future will be pointed to a perhaps better one with better answers. It's generally preferred to maintain one "canonical" question/answer than to have many duplicates with duplicate information strewn around the site.

Comment: @indivisible Also, two other posts have asked the same thing and been marked as duplicates of that one: this is the third. We're developing a network of questions that lead back to that one despite the fact that it has gone unanswered as a [meta-tag:feature-request] (not declined or accepted).

Comment: I was toying with a feature request of my own earlier for adding a mod only tag [feature-considered] or [under-consideration] to give feedback to posters whether there request is actually being looked at by staff/those with the power to escalate a feature-request. That's all a bit off-topic though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way for you to revoke the flag.

Comment: Bummer. I just did the same thing as the OP. :(